# R - How do the methods in goodfit() (package vcd) calculate degrees of freedom?

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit, negative-binomial-distribution, degrees-of-freedom

I have counts and I am trying to determine if they conform to the negative binomial distribution.  I am using goodfit() from the vcd package, however the two methods are giving me conflicting results:

```
library(vcd)
data = c(8,3,17,6,34,5,16,8,2,4,1,10,3,6,16,10,5,14,5,6,21,21,17,4,3,6)
minchisq = goodfit(data, type = "nbinomial", method = "MinChisq")
ml = goodfit(data, type = "nbinomial", method = "ML")
```

In the case of minchisq, the df is 32 and P = 0.5632191 (therefore I would not reject the null that the data conform to the negative binomial).

However, in the case of ml, the df is 10 and P = 3.247571e-05 (therefore I would reject the null that these data come from the negative binomial).

It seems like the result lies in how the df are calculated for each method.  What is the difference?  And is one more correct than the other?

Comment: Although framed in terms of R, asking about different tests & how the df are calculated should be on topic here, IMO.